# Syntax error while updating sqlite database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a error while updating data. The error is:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "parth": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE income SET income_balance=? WHERE
>   income_name=?parth

```
public void update2( String name, String bal){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //values.put(INCOME_NAME, name);
    values.put(INCOME_BALANCE, bal);
    db.update(TABLE_INCOME, values, INCOME_NAME+"=?"+name, new String[]{String.valueOf(name)});
```

Comment: db.update(TABLE_INCOME, values, INCOME_NAME+"=?", new String[]{name});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `INCOME_NAME+"=?"+name` with `INCOME_NAME+"=?"` (without `+name`, you are setting this value with `new String[]{String.valueOf(name)}` line)

```
db.update(TABLE_INCOME, values, INCOME_NAME+"=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(name)});
```

or eventually

```
db.update(TABLE_INCOME, values, INCOME_NAME+"='"+name+"'", null);
```